# Send SVG content though ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, svg

I'm working on a project where I have a Bussiness Card SVG. and some input where the change some text and color of the card.

After that, I'm getting all the SVG content and send to a server that creates a pdf through TCPDF library and sends the mail.

The code runs perfectly locally but the ajax fail on the client. I try to find the problem but didn't get any success.

Here is the code

```
  var front = $('#show_card .front_print').html();
  var back = $('#show_card .back_print').html();
  var data = $(this).serialize() + '&action=send_query' +
    '&front_side=' +  encodeURIComponent(front) +
    '&back_side=' +  encodeURIComponent(back);


  $.ajax({
      url: ajaxurl,
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('.image_loader').show();
        $('input[name="submit_order"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    })
    .done(function() {
      $('.image_loader').hide();
      $('.success_msg').show();
      $('#form_complete').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain how it's failing exactly? Is the response bad, or are you getting a js error?

Comment: It gives the 404 error. But if I send the ajax without SVG content it works okay.

Comment: So the server answers. Why does it answer with 404? Your description implies only the POST payload changes, not the resource adress. What does your server code look like?

Comment: Edit your question to include the content of `ajaxurl` and `data`, both with and without the SVG data added. That should help us see what the problem is.